# Issues with using Stopwatch in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, stopwatch

I have a function that's supposed to happen every X seconds until Y seconds pass.
There's a `long TickTime;` and `long Duration;` variables, and a Stopwatch object that's supposed to count the time.
At first, the method that was ran was this:

```
public override bool ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
{
    Timer.Start();

    while (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < Duration)
        if (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)
            ApplyTick(unit);
    Timer.Stop();
    return true;
}
```

And what happened was that the `while` just took over the thread the game was running on, so I split it into:

```
public override bool ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
{
    Thread trd = new Thread(() => ThreadMethod(unit));
    trd.Start();
    return true;
}

private void ThreadMethod(IUnit unit)
{
    Timer.Start();

    while (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < Duration)
        if (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)
            ApplyTick(unit);

    Timer.Stop();
}
```

ApplyTick is method of an abstract class, from which I've created a derived class that implemented the function this way:

```
[....]

int Damage { get; private set; }

[....]   

protected override void ApplyTick(IUnit unit)
{
    Damage += 5;
}
```

What happened after the first piece of code (the one that just stuck the thread until the duration passed) is that the number shown in a debug print was above 100000, wheres the base value was 10.

When I changed to the thread method, same thing happened only the number got bigger and
It didn't get the game thread stuck.

To fix this, I chose a different way, using Thread.Sleep

```
private void ThreadMethod(IUnit unit)
{
    int timeWaited = 0;
    int sleepTime = int.Parse(TickTime.ToString());

    while (timeWaited < Duration)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
        ApplyTick(unit);
        timeWaited += sleepTime;
    }
}
```

This did fix the problem, but I feel that something will eventually go wrong if
I use thread.sleep instead of using a stopwatch.
Can anyone explain why is this happening when I do use the stopwatch?

Comment: You should post the answer as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: Will do. Can I close my own post or do I have to wait for a mod to do that?

Comment: Don't close it. Just add an answer and mark it as answered.

Comment: So I'll have to wait 2 days, since it says "you can't accept your own answer for 2 days"

Comment: Yup. It's annoying, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by chaning the if from

```
if (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)
```

to

```
if (Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)
```

Why does it work? I don't know.
Seems that fooStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds should return the save value as fooStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds yet that is not the case.